# Await is not working inside an if condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise

I'm trying to save a document in mongodb collection and want to wait for it finish before the JavaScript executes next instruction but the await is not waiting

```js
const properties = ["name", "description", "type", "permission", "color"];

const addEvent = async (eventInfo, api_call = true) => {
    let response = { success: true };

    for (let prop of properties) {
        if (prop !== "permission" && !eventInfo.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            response.success = false;
            response.message = prop + " field is not given.";
            break;
        }
    }

    if (response.success) {
        let event = new Event(eventInfo);

        await event.save((err) => {
            if (err) {
                response.success = false;
                response.message = err.message;
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                response.success = true;
                response.message = "Event Added.";
            }
        });

        console.log(response);
    }

    if (api_call) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            response.success ? resolve(response) : reject(response);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Does `event.save` return a promise?

Comment: It doesn't appear to: Most functions that return a promise don't bother taking callbacks, instead relying on Promise's natural abilities (via `then` and `catch`).

Comment: Why you are using await if you are getting a response after calling the ```event.save()```. Is there any response(Promise) you are waiting for? And event.save(err) is itself waiting for the error so await doesn't make a sense there.

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal to use a callback with `async-await`. I'd restructure the code as below:

```js
let event = new Event(eventInfo);

try {
  await event.save();
  response.success = true;
  response.message = "Event Added.";
} catch (err) {
  response.success = false;
  response.message = err.message;
}

console.log(response);
```

You should either use callbacks for promises or use async-await but not both.

Comment: I'm assuming that `Event` here is a model returned by an ORM like mongoose. Yes, `save` function returns a promise.

Comment: Yes, it's mentioned in the documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save